# Migrated questions that got closed miss the close message

Tags: support, closed-questions, migration

The following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588785/is-looking-for-wi-fi-access-points-purely-passive-closed) was migrated from superuser to stackoverflow, and got closed somehow.

How? this information doesn't there. I have know idea why it closed, except that it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migrated questions are closed by definition.